# Cannot include js and css file in google cloud app

Tags: angularjs, .htaccess, google-app-engine, cloud, google-cloud-storage

I am using lamp deployment, using Cloud sql. After uploading my project to xxx.appspot.com. All the css and js files are not opening. It throws:

> Error: Not Found The requested URL /public/js/admin/custom.js was not
>   found on this server.

I am adding the css file as below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://syncspot-ds.appspot.com/public/css/admin/login.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://syncspot-ds.appspot.com/public/css/admin/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://syncspot-ds.appspot.com/public/css/admin/font-awesome.css">
```

My app.yaml file is as below:

```
application: xxx
version: 1
runtime: php55
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:

- url: /public/css/admin
  static_dir: /public/css/admin

- url: /public/css/front
  static_dir: /public/css/front

- url: /public/css/front/images
  static_dir: /public/css/front/images

- url: /public/fonts
  static_dir: /public/fonts

- url: /public/images
  static_dir: /public/images

- url: /public/images/00-ICON LOGO
  static_dir: /public/images/00-ICON LOGO

- url: /public/images/admin
  static_dir: /public/images/admin

- url: /public/images/background
  static_dir: /public/images/background

- url: /public/images/icons
  static_dir: /public/images/icons

- url: /public/images/logo
  static_dir: /public/images/logo

- url: /public/js/admin
  static_dir: /public/js/admin

- url: /public/js/front
  static_dir: /public/js/front

- url: /public/js/gmap
  static_dir: /public/js/gmap

- url: /public/swf
  static_dir: /public/swf

- url: /public/uploads/channel_content
  static_dir: /public/uploads/channel_content

- url: /public/uploads/profile_img
  static_dir: /public/uploads/profile_img 

- url: /.*
  script: index.php
```

My .htaccess file is as below:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

I am using Code Igniter, AngularJS and MySql. If I use an external css say:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://1223.123.123.123/xxx/public/css/admin/login.css">
```

It is working properly.

Please help me so that I can make a link to css or js file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the static directories, the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig?hl=en#Python_app_yaml_Static_directory_handlers) does not have the leading "/" in the static_dir section.

Try to use this format:

```
- url: /public/css/admin
  static_dir: public/css/admin
```

Comment: Why don't you just make the whole public directory static? Then you don't need all this configuration.